# Trying to implement flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I am trying to create a skeleton and I am using flask security for the login/admin.

Inside my app folder I have a function where I create my app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

from .views.home import home_blueprint
from .views.contact import contact_blueprint
from .views.login import login_blueprint, bcrypt, login_manager
from .models import db
from .models.user import User, Role

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(contact_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(login_blueprint)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)
    return app
```

Now the issue comes up when I try to create a dummy admin user to test.
For this I have a create_db.py file in the skeleton root folder.

```
from app import create_app
from sqlalchemy import exists
from flask_security.utils import encrypt_password

from app.models import db
from app.models.user import Role, User

create_app().app_context().push()
db.create_all()

user_role = Role(name='user')
db.session.add(user_role)
db.session.commit()

super_user_role = Role(name='superuser')
db.session.add(super_user_role)
db.session.commit()

user_role = Role(name='user')
super_user_role = Role(name='superuser')
admin_user = user_datastore.create_user(
    username='admin',
    email='admin',
    password=encrypt_password('admin'),
    confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
    roles=[user_role, super_user_role]
)
db.session.commit()
```

When I run this I get NameError: user_datastore not define?

For story purpose, I implemented flask-login first and was able to get create a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file create_db.py the variable `user_datastore` doesn't exist hence the error. You could do something like the following in `create_dy.py` (untested):

```
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
# get the app security instance
security = app.extensions.get('security')
# or like this
# security = app.extensions['security']


# ... etc

# Use the security api to create users
admin_user = security.datastore.create_user(
    username='admin',
    email='admin',
    password=encrypt_password('admin'),
    confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
    roles=[user_role, super_user_role]
)

# ... etc
```

Also I'm not sure you need to `login_manager.init_app(app)` in your `create_app()` function.

Comment: This one part of the code absolutely opened the world for me with flask-security; `security = app.extensions.get('security')`